# How to select a dropdown value in another page?

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu

I have a gravityforms script on my wordpress site. It just creates easily editable forms. I need somehow to send a query **from a link** to choose a proper item in dropdown list.

[scheme http://agency-ct.ru/dropdown.jpg](http://agency-ct.ru/dropdown.jpg)

Comment: Nice diagram, but can you show some code? Or explain better, what happens of Page 1? Gravity Form? Or GF is on Page 2?